# How to create reusable interceptors in ktor?

Tags: kotlin, routes, ktor

In ktor, it appears the way to do customized permissions checks is through interceptors, like so:

```
route("/portal") {
   route("articles") { … }
   route("admin") {


    intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Features) { … } // verify admin privileges
      route("article/{id}") { … } // manage article with {id}
      route("profile/{id}") { … } // manage profile with {id}
   }
}
```

What is the best way to extract the interceptor logic for reuse for other routes elsewhere in the codebase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sorry to be late. In my code, I made routes, some routes have an interceptor to measure and log the time of the execution where as others not. So I have made a function to do so following the exemple in the documentation (https://ktor.io/advanced/pipeline/route.html#) and then I have but this function around a block of routes that needed to be measured.

Please find my code below

```
install(Routing) {
    val konfig = HoconKonfigAdapter()
    val contextPath = konfig.get("ktor.deployment.context-path")
    route("$contextPath/api/v1") {
        val registry = feature(Metrics).registry

        healthEndPoints()
        metricsEndPoints(registry)
        routeWithMeasureTime {
            catalogSiEndPoints()
            reunionCatalogEditoEndPoints()
            telesurveillanceCatalogEditoEndPoints()
            catalogLegacyEndPoints()
        }
    }
}
```

all the routes inside the block routeWithMeasureTime will be intercepted and measured. The other one, no.

Hope it helps event so late.